# set target framework for virtual directory NSIS

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, nsis

how can i set the Target Framework of Virtual Directory ?
i am creating the Virtual Directory using "NsisIIS::CreateVDir" command in NSIS.

is there any way to set the Target framework to .net 4.0 fro this created VD ?

Thanks

Comment: I'm having the same problem - I can't seem to set the Application Pool (or any of the other params). The limited documentation states that using the user variables $0-$5 will work but I'm having no luck :-(

Comment: Looks like my issues (above) are related to IIS7 - works fine on IIS6.

Answer (score 0):

Iknow it is an old post, but if anybody is looking and finds this post, may be this helps.

I used:

```
Section "Aplicacion de administracion"

; Set output path to the installation directory.
SetOutPath "$INSTDIR\WebApp"

; Primary project outputs
File /r /x *.config "Precompiled\WebApp\*.*"

; Config files
SetOverwrite off
    File "Precompiled\WebApp\*.config"
SetOverwrite on

StrCpy $1 "SDGCC App Pool"

NsisIIS::CreateVDir "WebApplication" "$INSTDIR\WebApp" 

SectionEnd
```

and it worked fine. Be sure than the app pool exits.

Hope this help.